# Программа не читает один из делителей(питон)

Tags: python

Cовершенным называется число, равное сумме всех своих делителей, строго меньших его самого. Например, число 6 является совершенным, так как 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. На вход программе подаётся натуральное число N, определите, является ли оно совершенным.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаётся натуральное число N.

Формат выходных данных
Если число N является совершенным, выведите строку "Число N является совершенным". В противном случае выведите строку "Число N не является совершенным". Конечно же, вместо символа "N" должно быть выведено само число.

```
Sample Input 1:

6

Sample Output 1:

Число 6 является совершенным

Sample Input 2:

37

Sample Output 2:

Число 37 не является совершенным
```

есть код к этой задаче:

```
N = int(input())
i = 1
a = 0
while i * i <= N:
    if N % i == 0:
        a += i
        if i != N // i:
            a += N // i
    i += 1
if N == a:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " является совершенным")
else:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " не является совершенным")
```

прога не читает 1 как делитель, как это исправить?

Comment: Что-то странное вы говорите. Взял вашу программу, запустил, Получил: "1
Число 1 является совершенным". Что не так?

Comment: Не понял смысла этого `if i != N // i: a += N // i`, думаю лучше убрать. и ошибка в условии цикал, не `i * i` надо, а `i * 2`

Comment: Условие в цикле верное.

Answer (score 2):

В этом коде есть некоторые неточности:

```
N = int(input())
i = 1
a = 0
while i * i <= N: # Здесь идёт проверка делителей данного числа до его корня.
    if N % i == 0:
        a += i
        if i != N // i: # Здесь мы проверяем не является ли i корнем N
            a += N // i # (i != N // i) => i * i != N
    i += 1
if N == a:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " является совершенным")
else:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " не является совершенным")
```

Допустим если взять число 36, то его корень - это 6, но у данного числа есть делители большие 6 - это 9, 12, 18 - мы видим, что делители числа доходят до его половины включительно.

Вот исправленный код:

```
N = int(input())
i = 1
a = 0
while i * 2 <= N: # Делители числа не больше его половины
    if N % i == 0:
        a += i
    i += 1
if N == a:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " является совершенным")
else:
    print("Число " + str(N) + " не является совершенным")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Непонятно для чего вы используете эти строки:

```py
if i != N // i:
    a += N // i
```

2. У вас неверное условие в цикле.
3. Проще использовать цикл `for`:

```py
N = int(input())
a = 0  # сумма делителей
for i in range(1, N):
    if N%i == 0:
        a += i
# вывод
```

4. Если нужен именно `while`:

```py
N = int(input())
a = 0 # сумма делителей
i = 1
while i<N:
    if N%i == 0:
        a += i
    i+=1
# вывод
```

---

"Однострочник"

```py
N = int(input())
print(f'Число {N} ', '' if N==sum(i for i in range(1, N) if not N%i) else 'не ', 'является совершенным.'
```